# Best edition of Arkfen's Mathematical Methods for Physicists

Tags: book-recommendation

I want to buy a physical edition of Arkfen's Mathematical Methods for Physicists. Seventh edition is listed at 100 USD. A friend is selling his Second edition for 35 USD. Is it worth to buy the second edition, or should I buy the newest one?

Edit: I do not live in the USA

Comment: $35 for a 2nd edition seems a bit high- you can find copies for sale online for much less. However, it's really a matter of opinion whether the newer editions offer a substantial benefit.

Comment: https://www.abebooks.com/Mathematical-Methods-Physicists-Arfken-Weber-Harris/30183584060/bd?cm_mmc=gmc-_-new-_-PLA-_-v01&gclid=Cj0KCQiAgf3gBRDtARIsABgdL3n6Se2AICxnz9nDRu8HDcJfthMqt0x3dis3HFwfkAQFdZhDn3TufFgaAmUiEALw_wcB